# Convert long string into array and indexes

Tags: php

If we have variable with string like :

`$str = "This is test text and I'd like to split it";`

How can I get it to print each specific word as array item in `foreach` or `for` loop, so array would look like ([0]=>This, [1]=>is ... )

Thanks!

Comment: `foreach(explode(' ',$str) as $word) { ... }`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, like this:

```
<?php

    $str = "This is test text and I'd like to split it";

    $array = explode(" ", $str);

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
0 => This
1 => is
2 => test
3 => text
4 => and
5 => I'd
6 => like
7 => to
8 => split
9 => it
```

**Edited:**

If you want to print only certain number of elements then use `for` instead of `foreach`.

```
<?php

    $str = "This is test text and I'd like to split it";

    $array = explode(" ", $str);

    for($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i){
        echo $i . "=>" . $array[$i] . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
0=>This
1=>is
2=>test
```

Comment: And if i'd like to print only certain number of words(3 or 5 or anything) so my output looks like `This is test` ?

Comment: Ah got it. `$str="This is testing of a array printing";
$i=0;
foreach(explode(' ', $str) as $word){
 $i++;
 if($i>=3) break;
  echo $word." ";
}` Thanks!

Comment: @Michael You can also use `for` loop for that purpose. See the **edited** section of my answer.